Spring UnsatisfiedDependencyException, Error creating bean with name
I have my security config class like this
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${cors-allow-origin.url}")
    private String corsAllowOriginUrl;

    @Autowired
    private PermissionService permissionService;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager(http))
                .httpBasic(basic -> basic.disable())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
//Other urls
                });
        return http.build();
    }

On the logs i've got the following
| ERROR | TomcatStarter - Error starting Tomcat context. Exception:
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. 
 Message: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied 
 dependency expressed through field 'permissionService': Error 
 creating
 bean with name 'permissionService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
 through field 'roleRepository': No qualifying bean of type 
 'package-route.RoleRepository' available: expected at 
 least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
 annotations: 
 {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I have the permissions service with (I believe) the proper annotations
@Service
@Transactional
public class PermissionService {

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

Finally, the role repository like this
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<RoleEntity, String> {
    Optional<RoleEntity> findByName(String name);
    Optional<List<RoleEntity>> findAllByPermissions(PermissionEntity permission);


}

All these errors started to appear when updating the SecurityConfig from Spring 2 to Spring 3.
Ththis is the main class, on the same level as the folders where those classes are located at
package io.inowise.inox;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class InoxApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InoxApplication.class, args);
    }

}


In which packages are SecurityConfig, RoleRepositoy and PermissionService?

@Matheus security config: package io.inowise.inox.security;
permissions service: package io.inowise.inox.services;
role repository: package io.inowise.inox.repositories;
As far as i know, with ComponentScan added to the SecurityConfig class, should make it enough so it can locate them, right?

Not actually. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html.

Your SecurityConfig, PermissionService and RoleRepository reside, respectively on io.inowise.inox.security, io.inowise.inox.services and io.inowise.inox.repositories.
You are annotating @SecurityConfig with @EnableJpaRepositories. This fact is instructing Spring to search for Spring Data JPA Repositories at the io.inowise.inox.security package, which, given your project structure, is wrong, because your repositories are meant to be at io.inowise.inox.repositories.
From @EnableJpaRepositories javadoc:

Annotation to enable JPA repositories. Will scan the package of the annotated configuration class for Spring Data repositories by default.

You have some options to solve this issue:
One solution: the most common is probably by using Spring Boot with it's out of the box auto configuration.
If you have the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency in your project, it will bring the auto-configuration class for Spring Data JPA Repositories and you'll have to do nothing more. Just remove the @EnableJpaRepositories from the SecurityConfig class and that is it. This works for most projects.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

Another solution is to tell the @EnableJpaRepository annotation the base package you want to scan for repositories:
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "io.inowise.inox.repositories" })

I suggest sticking with the first approach, because it works out of the box for most situations and let's be honest: the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation has nothing to do with security configurations, so, it's presence on a SecurityConfig class is weird.

I've removed the EnableJpaRepositories from the SecurityConfig, however it gives the same error, also tried the second option you gave me, same result.
What you replied makes a lot of sense, and chathpt gave it an ok, however its still not working and it might be something about a configuration.

@Unai you're sure it is the very same error? Also, please, add to your question where your bootstrap class resides and its code (the class with the main method)

Now the error is pretty similar:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException.
Message: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied
dependency expressed through field 'permissionService': Error
creating
bean with name 'permissionService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed
through field 'roleRepository': No qualifying bean of type
'package-route.RoleRepository' available: expected at
least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

@Unai. . . Do you have spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency in your project, or do you have the standalone spring-data-jpa dependency in your project?

i have spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, version 3.1.4 @Matheus
